# Linux keyboard config (xkb) for three Shift keys

Tags: linux, keyboard, shift

I am looking for a way to define an additional <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, for a given key scan code. So that I would end up with unchanged left and right <kbd>shift</kbd>, plus an extra <kbd>shift</kbd> key, which would be definable on any existing key (assuming I know its scan code).

In xkb/keycodes, I see <kbd>shift</kbd> keycodes defined for:

```
<LFSH>
<RTSH>
```

But if I was to add a third entry here, I don't know I'd tell xkb that it was also to be considered a <kbd>Shift</kbd> key.

(This is not relevant to the question, but in case you wondered, the use case is for some keyboards which have a split <kbd>spacebar</kbd>, where I would like to set one of the <kbd>spacebar</kbd> halves to be the extra <kbd>Shift</kbd>).

Interested on what xkb configuration I would need for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can do this using xmodmap, if you rename the keycode to keysym Shift_L, and add the Shift_L back
into the modifier map. Eg for keycode 110:

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 110 = Shift_L Shift_L Shift_L Shift_L'
xmodmap -e 'add shift = Shift_L Shift_R'
```

Find the keycode by looking through `xmodmap -pke` or using `xev` or similar.

Comment: Yes, this works. Would be nice if it could be all done in xkb, but this is still an acceptable solution. I would note that only the first line is required for get it to work for me; the second line appears to have no additional effect.

Comment: @Steve Good to know. I'm not entirely clear how xmodmap interacts with  xkb, so this is another interesting snippet of info.

Answer (score 1):

I have now found a way to achieve the above directly in xkb configuration, without the need to use xmodmap.

**STEP ONE:** In the xkb/symbols/pc file, note the following is already defined:

```
key <LFSH> {    [ Shift_L       ]   };
key <RTSH> {    [ Shift_R       ]   };
```

So, what is required as to add a new key definition for MDSH (ie "mid shift"):

```
key <MDSH> {    [ Shift_L       ]   };
```

**STEP TWO:** Assign these keys to the keycodes. In xkb/keycodes/evdev, left and right shift are already defined:

```
<LFSH> = 50;
<RTSH> = 62;
```

So all that remains to add an extra definition for MDSH:

```
<MDSH> = XXX;
```

where XXX is the keycode you want to assign.